# RuntimeError: Attempted to send CUDA tensor received from another process; this is not currently supported. Consider cloning before sending

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing

I'm new to pytorch multiprocessing and I'm trying to train a network while evaluating at the same time. I'm trying to use pytorch multiprocessing to share a network model between process

##### Issue

I can't share tensors between a process and a loop

##### Packages

Python (3.8.10)
[pip] Pytorch (1.10.0+cu113)
[pip] Numpy (1.23.0)

##### Sample Code

```
    import time
    import copy
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    import torch.multiprocessing as mp
    
    def training_thread(model, thread_data):
    criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=3e-4, weight_decay=1e-7)

    # Run loop until stop signal arrives
    while not thread_data['stop_thread']:
        if thread_data['data'] is not None:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # Put network in training mode
            model.train()
            x = model(thread_data['data'])
            loss = criterion(x, thread_data['label'])

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        time.sleep(1)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        return x

class MAIN:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dtype  = torch.float32
        self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        print('device:', self.device)

        shared_model = Net()
        shared_model.type(self.dtype).to(self.device)
        shared_model.eval()

        shared_model.share_memory()

        self.thread_data = mp.Manager().dict()
        self.thread_data['stop_thread'] = False
        self.thread_data['data'] = None
        self.thread_data['label'] = torch.zeros(16,20,16,16).to(self.device)

        p = mp.Process(target=training_thread, args=(shared_model, self.thread_data,))
        p.start()

        try:
            while True:
                self.thread_data['data'] = torch.rand(16,1,24,24).to(self.device)

                self.run_evaluation(shared_model)
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('interrupted!')

        self.thread_data['stop_thread'] = True
        p.join()

    def run_evaluation(self, model):
        model.eval()
        x = model(self.thread_data['data'])
        print('evaluation is running')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    MAIN()
```